# How to edit credentials in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

How do I edit the credentials that are showing up in jenkins?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have permission you should have an option to update credetials when you point the name column: [image]

Comment: Thanks! The UX here is a little suspect.

Comment: Alternatively you can click on the credentials name (so that you get to the page for the specific credential) and then select update in the left hand side menu.

Comment: But the property "Name" cannot be edited.